# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rubyzip"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I tried to add docx-html gem to my project and here's what I get while `bundle install`:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rubyzip":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       zip-zip (>= 0) ruby depends on
>         rubyzip (>= 1.0.0) ruby
>
> ```
> docx-html (>= 0) ruby depends on
>   docx (~> 0.1.0) ruby depends on
>     rubyzip (0.9.1)
> ```

Part of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'zip-zip'
gem 'docx_replace'
```

I added the line `gem 'zip-zip'` by an advice from another StackOverflow question. If I exclude it, instead of bundle install error I get the following error while trying to start the server:

> `require': cannot load such file -- zip

How do I get rid of these errors while keeping gem docx_replace?

Comment: what is the source that you are pulling your gems from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet figured out why, but for some reason changing Gemfile code to this worked:

```
gem 'zip'
gem 'docx_replace'
```